# Access entity id inside Hibernate Usertype

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have created my own hibernate UserType implementation class and it works as expected.

I have a requirement now where i need to have access to the value of "id" field of a particular entity record (which is generated via sequence) inside my Hibernate UserType implementation class. Is it possible to achieve this?

Below is my UserType Implementation:

```
    public class SecureStringType implements UserType {

        @Override
        public int[] sqlTypes() {
            return new int[] { Types.VARCHAR };
        }
        @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return SecureString.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws SQLException {

        String encryptedValue = rs.getString(names[0]);

        getDataSecurityService().getActualValue(encryptedValue);
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
        secureString.setActualValue(decryptedValue);
        return secureString;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            SecureString actualValue = (SecureString) value;
            st.setString(index, getDataSecurityService().encrypt(actualValue ));
        }
    }

// DeepCopy, disassemble, assemble method implementations
    }
```

I have noticed that `SharedSessionContractImplementor` has the `PersistentContext` inside which has list of all entities that are loaded, but I don't have a way to determine for which Entity the UserType is being called.

```
`session.getPersistenceContext().getEntitiesByKey();` has all the `EntityKey` objects  but I need to get the one for which this `UserType` is being called currently.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please show the code

Comment: @Ndumiso Does this really require a code? It can be any implementation of Hibernate UserType interface. And inside that implementation, i need access to id field of my entity

Comment: "I have created my own hibernate UserType implementation class" if it's the same as your Entity class, then you can say easily, `UserType ut;` then `ut.getId();`  or ,`ut.setId(id);`

Comment: @Ndumiso Added code

Comment: @RezaPayambari I don't understand what you are saying. A UserType is an interface that Hibernate provides and its implementation is separate from the Entity itself

Comment: ok, I didn't know about UserType, but as I now read some articles, there's a relation between Entities and UserType Implementation, could you also show that part, I mean the relation between them. It's now interesting for me to find a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem in my codebase. AFAIK, the only option I could find as of yet is to add an ID field in your SecureString type, set it during @PreUpdate/@PreLoad or other callbacks, or in getters and setters/constructors, or set it using an HibernateInterceptor at whatever lifecycle that suits you. You can then access it in nullSafeSet using value.getId() or something. Its nutty, but it works.